# How to change property of indivudal buttons in vuetify data-table?

Tags: javascript, datatable, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify data-table which renders the data received from axios call.

On the last column I'm using template v-slot for bespoke column so I can add two buttons. v-btn accepts has two props for loading state as per the documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons#loaders:

- :loading
- :disabled

---

The problem is that when I call a function that changes those values, all of the buttons in the data table are receiving the prop state so instead of 1 button displying loader, all of them are.

```html
<v-row no-gutters>      
                <v-data-table
                :headers="tableHeaders"
                :items="requests"
                :items-per-page="10"
                class="elevation-1"
                :loading="loading" loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
                >

                <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
                    <v-btn color="success" @click="createPacks(item)" :loading="createloading" :disabled="createloading">Create</v-btn>
                    <v-btn color="error" @click="excludeRequest(item)" :loading="cancelloading" :disabled="cancelloading">Cancel</v-btn>     
                </template>
                </v-data-table>
            </v-row>
```

I'm aware this is because the buttons in the DOM are not unique and the framework is calling all of them but I have no idea how to change that default behaviour.

---

**Data:**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            loading: null,
            error: null,
            tableHeaders: [
                {
                    text: 'ID',
                    value: 'req_id',
                    align: 'center',
                },
                { text: 'Template', value: 'templateConcatenated'},
                { text: 'No of batches', value: 'no_batches' },
                { text: 'Batch size', value: 'batch_size' },
                { text: 'Date requested', value: 'requested_at' },
                { text: 'Requested by', value: 'requester' },
                { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false, align: 'center'},
            ],

            createloading: false,
            cancelloading: false,
            successmessage: '',
            errormessage: '',

        };
    },
    methods: {

        createPacks(item) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.createloading = true;
            let page_url = '/api/CreateProcedure?api_token='+this.$api_token;
            axios
                .post(page_url, item)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.loading = false;

                    this.error = null;
                    this.createloading = false;
                    this.successmessage = 'Packs created successfully!';
                    this.errormessage = null;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    this.createloading = false;
                    this.successmessage = null;
                    this.errormessage = 'Error creating the packs: '+err;
                    console.log("error: "+err);
                })
        },

    }
}
```

Any idea how to call each individual button to change it's state?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to set the loading properties on the item itself instead of defining them globally:

```
createPacks(item) {
        this.loading = true;
        item.createloading = true;
        let page_url = '/api/CreateProcedure?api_token='+this.$api_token;
        axios
            .post(page_url, item)
            .then((response) => {
                this.loading = false;

                this.error = null;
                item.createloading = false;
                this.successmessage = 'Packs created successfully!';
                this.errormessage = null;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                item.createloading = false;
                this.successmessage = null;
                this.errormessage = 'Error creating the packs: '+err;
                console.log("error: "+err);
            })
    },
```

---

**== UPDATE ==**

I added a code based on the codepen you added in the comments, you have to use item.createloasing also in the HTML else it is not working. https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/LYPerLg?editors=1010

Currently only one button is working at the same time but this is probably because of axios is not defined in the codepen.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that and tried again just now but without a luck.
If I'm replacing this.creatloading with item.createloading, the loader is not showing on the button at all.
The loader is there as there's another function that I've stripped out from the promise which I have to reset :)

Comment: Do you have a working example in e.g. codepen, jsfiddle or codesandbox?

Comment: Thanks @dreijntjens - can you share the link, code as mine is not updated?

Comment: I can not update you code pen. You can only update you own codepens

Comment: Ahh I see, sorry I thought you've updated my pen for some reason... long day today. Thanks, it's perfect! :)